# Why does report.c say I'm listening on port 80_80 and have less Cores than available?

Tags: java, multithreading, g-wan

**Environment**

I'm running `G-WAN` on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 SERVER LTS (3.19.0-49) 64-bit` with a CPU **Intel Core i7-3610QM** using the **TCP port 80**.

There's the `0.0.0.0:80` folder but no `0.0.0.0:8080` nor any `0.0.0.0:xyz` other folder.

Why do both the `report.c` and `report.java` servlets respond:

> 1 host(s): 0.0.0.0:80_80 Vs. the right 0.0.0.0:80

?

At the same time, these two servlets report:

> CPU(s): 1 5x R) Core(TM)i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30 GHz (1 Core(s)/CPU, 1 Thread(s)/Core)

and Allowed: 5 Cores!

when this CPU is a **4 Cores** with **dual threads** and then these servlets should return:

> (4 Core(s)/CPU, 2 Thread(s)/Core and Allowed: 8 Cores?

[Short technical view of the Intel Core i7-3610QM](http://cpuboss.com/cpu/Intel-Core-i7-3610QM)

BTW, wouldn't it be more accurate to respond:

> Allowed 8 Threads Vs. 8 Cores?

Comment: It prints what it prints. Why ask us?

Comment: @EJP, thank you for this nice question. As a matter of fact, I was expecting an answer from the G-WAN team and obviously... I got it.

Answer (score 0):

On my Desktop I have the following:

```
CPU(s): 1x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU W3680 @ 3.33GHz (6 Core(s)/CPU, 2 Thread(s)/Core)
Allowed: 12 Cores
```

That's the expected information.

I don't have your CPU, nor your system configuration, so I can't test and tell you what happens behind the scene in your particular case.

There are many things that can make CPU and CPU Cores detection differ from the physically installed hardware, among which your specific `system configuration` (policies can block Cores), `hypervisors`, and faulty detection.

G-WAN tries to find on its own with the `CPU ID` instruction, and then it checks what the Linux kernel reports. When the result is different, it becomes complicated to tell why and to pick then the "right" answer.

Your question about the *"Allowed"* 'threads' vs 'cores' terminology is more complicated than you imagine and 'cores' is the lesser evil here.

For the "listener" format I also get this:

```
1 host(s): 0.0.0.0:8080_8080
Root: #0.0.0.0
```

So, yes, there's a double port incorrectly reported here, probably due to the numerous new options implemented recently. It will be fixed.

Finally, `stackoverflow` is a programmer Q&A site so I suggest that you use `serverfault` for basic G-WAN usage and system issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gil for your answer even if it doesn't fix the problem yet.

Please be aware that on my machine, htop shows the 8 cores when report.c and report.java don't.

I'll go on serverfault for further questions about other servlet glitches.

BTW, nice desktop you've ;)

Just to know, what Linux distribution and release do you use for your tests?

Answer (score 0):

I just dowwloaded the last gwan full install script made by Fnux and installed the gwan 7.12.6 release with all the 15 available programming languages and it did the job nicely.

Now, both the report.c and report.java servlets show the right listener but still omit to display the System Uptime values.

Further, when reloading these two servlets several times (using the F5 keystroke), the page displays strange characters (i.e. ">" or "?>" or "??" or "T?") right above the Traffic title.

Is it a problem with the internal gwan cache (on my system, the init.c file is disabled with an underscore character placed after its extention like this: "init.c_")?

Thank you to Gil to fix it at his earliest convenience.